# setup WAN miniport(PPPOE) internet connection

Tags: pppoe

I want to setup my GTPL (i.e. the service provider) PPPOE internet connection in ubuntu 12.04 .

I tried to configure my internet connection in Fedora 16 using the following method which worked fine.

I've tried to go to Edit Connection > then to the DSL tab > then ADD>enter my username and password > Save.
But this method didn't help in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: did you try rebooting?

Comment: ye smany a times but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo pppoeconf`, it will present you with a setup wizard, just accept default values and enter your username and password, it'll ask you if you want to connect at boot-time, preferably answer this with no if you don't want to be connected automatically on boot. After it is completed you can start your network connection with `sudo pon dsl-provider` and disconnect it with `sudo poff`.

Comment: thank you very much now I'm connected 2 internet(commented via ubuntu 12.04)